# glibc detected free() invalid size (fast) error?

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error when I execute the following function and I have no idea what it means. Here is the function:

```
void readf2()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("f2",std::ios_base::binary);
    std::string str(2, '\0');
    int i = 0;
    while(inFile.read(&str[i],2)){
    cout<<"Success: ["<< i << "] = "<< (int)str[i];                        ;
    cout<<"\n";
    i++;
    }
}
```

The function works for a while writing various numbers to the console and then boom it crashes with this error, a backtrace, and a memory map. Is this happening because I am freeing a memory address that doesn't exist?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @littleadv I'm reading in a file that contains a bunch of binary numbers and I want to output them so I can see if it's working. What I have to do is save these numbers into an array of integers and then output it to a separate file.

Comment: Are you expecting `str` to be that array???

Comment: @littleadv no I just wanted to see if it was working. I actually don't know how I'm going to get the ints in the array. I thought maybe I can use `strtol` with my string as the argument but I don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're giving the [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) call a pointer to memory that doesn't belong to you.

[`str[i]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) returns an offset in the string, but it doesn't guarantee that you have enough memory to read **to** that location (+2).

What you probably meant was to have an array of `int`s, and use the `i` as an index on that:

```
void readf2()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("f2",std::ios_base::binary);
    std::vector< int >  str; // if you're reading int's - use int, not string
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while(inFile.read(&j,sizeof(int))){ // check what the content is here
    str.push_back(j);
    cout<<"Success: ["<< i << "] = "<< str[i];
    cout<<"\n";
    i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would I go about preventing this?

Comment: Now I'm getting a seg fault. I think it might be the while loop. I'lltry and tweak it

Comment: I'm guessing the `(int)str[i]` is not what you should be doing there. Why are you reading binary into a string to begin with? It all seems to be so wrong...

Comment: @Andy updated my suggested fix to actually deal with binary data, and not just fix the original error you had

Comment: I wanted to read it to a string just to see if it was reading correctly, I realize now that I could have just skipped that and stored it in an int array. which is my end goal anyway.

Comment: I was just doing this and didnt know how to call read using  an int, thank you!

Comment: @littledev the call to read isn't working saying cannot convert from int to basic istream <char *> should I try using `&j.c_str()`

Comment: you should probably cast `&j` to `(char*)&j`.

Comment: Or you can just use `inFile >> j`

Comment: @littledev figured it would be something like that and so I tried to do itoa(j,&pEnd,2) where pEnd is defined as `char * pEnd;` but it's not working and changing it to (char*)&j did not work either. I'll keep playing with the arguments

Comment: I would but the file contains binary numbers. Wouldn't this cause a problem? or is it acceptable? Thanks for all of your help by the way greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure I know what you mean by "binary numbers". You've been using strings, mentioned ltoa, it makes me wonder whether we're speaking the same language here.

Comment: the file contains "a set of numbers in binary format"? Not sure what that means now

Comment: After messing with it for a bit I got it to work using inFile >> j; but j was declared this way `int8_t j;`